# How does Homebrew compile sources? Is there any log?

Tags: macos, makefile, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I used Homebrew on MacOS to get the package "espeak". It builds and installs just fine and I can use it perfectly.

Now I would like to know where Homebrew gets the source code from and how the package is built. The source code I can get with the following command:

```
brew unpack --patch espeak
```

Which seems to be the official code from the sourceforge website of espeak.

Now I would like to know: how does Homebrew build the package? There is a "src" directory with a makefile, however, when I try to build it with

```
make
```

I get a Buch of warnings and errors like

```
ld: library not found for -lportaudio
```

even though port audio and pulse audio are installed. I would like to know if Homebrew uses any special flags etc. for the make command.
Any way to find out?

Comment: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/espeak

Comment: In concretion, you have to figure out where the dependent library was installed, and include that in the include path.